# Synonym not appearing in all_identifiers table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Good day,

I am encountering a strange issues where a public synonym for a PLSQL package is not appearing in the all_identifiers table.

I compiled the package header and body, created the public synonym for it.

If I check the all_objects table, I can see both the package object and synonym object for the package. But if I check the all_identifiers table, there isn't an entry for it.

1. When does the all_identifiers table get updated? I would have assumed on object/synonym compile.
2. Can I force the table to update?

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cut a long story short:

```
alter session set plscope_settings='IDENTIFIERS:ALL';
```

Read on [Using PL/Scope](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_plscope.htm#BABBDBFE).

---

**Demo**: there's nothing there (in `ALL_IDENTIFIERS`, that is):

```
SQL> create or replace package pkg_test as
  2    procedure p_test;
  3  end;
  4  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body pkg_test as
  2    procedure p_test is begin null; end;
  3  end;
  4  /

Package body created.

SQL> create public synonym syn_pkg_test for pkg_test;

Synonym created.

SQL> select owner, name, type from all_identifiers where name like 'SYN%TEST';

no rows selected

SQL>
```

---

Let's start over, but this time by altering the session first:

```
SQL> drop public synonym syn_pkg_test;

Synonym dropped.

SQL> alter session set plscope_settings='IDENTIFIERS:ALL';

Session altered.

SQL> create or replace package pkg_test as
  2    procedure p_test;
  3  end;
  4  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body pkg_test as
  2    procedure p_test is begin null; end;
  3  end;
  4  /

Package body created.

SQL> create public synonym syn_pkg_test for pkg_test;

Synonym created.

SQL> select owner, name, type from all_identifiers where name like 'SYN%TEST';

OWNER                          NAME                           TYPE
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------
PUBLIC                         SYN_PKG_TEST                   SYNONYM
PUBLIC                         SYN_PKG_TEST                   SYNONYM

SQL>
```

---

Ta-daaaa!

Comment: Wonderful, that did it. Had no idea about identifier-scoping, figured that was all handled automatically. Thank you.